# Conditionally load laravel api resource

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to conditionally load a property (not a relationship) in my API Resource class:

```
'animals' => $this->when(false, AnimalsResource::collection($this->animals), null),
```

I thought that if the condition was false it wouldn't try to load the property `animals`. However when I run this I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function first() on null
```

How can I remove the property `animals` from my api response json when it is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. The 'when' method only applies to the Api Resource, but you are still invoking the animals property.

You could set something like this

```
'animals' => $this->when(! is_null($this->animals), AnimalsResource::collection($this->animals), null),
```

Keep in mind that if you are executing a SQL Statement inside your 'animals' attribute, you could generate a N + 1 problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs to know all the parameters of a function before calling them.

Doing `AnimalsResource::collection($this->animals)` will actually generate the result so it can use it to call `when`.

You can try the following code instead:

```
'animals' => $this->when(false, function () { 
 return AnimalsResource::collection($this->animals); 
}, null),
```

in which case the parameter is a function instead of a collection which Laravel might invoke if the first parameter is true